# S3 Image uploading through S3TransferUtilitySample: "Unable to execute HTTP request"

Tags: android, ssl, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to upload an image to S3, but I am getting the below exception:

```
 17721-18106 E/UploadTask: Unable to execute HTTP request: Write error: ssl=0x6047a8b0: I/O error during system call, Connection reset by peer
 17721-17721 E/UploadActivity: Error during upload: 3
 17721-17721 E/UploadActivity: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Transfer failed.
 17721-17721 E/UploadActivity:     at com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.s3.transferutility.TransferObserver$TransferContentObserver.onChange(TransferObserver.java:219)
 17721-17721 E/UploadActivity:     at android.database.ContentObserver.onChange(ContentObserver.java:129)
 17721-17721 E/UploadActivity:     at android.database.ContentObserver$NotificationRunnable.run(ContentObserver.java:180)
 17721-17721 E/UploadActivity:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
17721-17721 E/UploadActivity:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
 17721-17721 E/UploadActivity:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
 17721-17721 E/UploadActivity:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5299)
 17721-17721 E/UploadActivity:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
 17721-17721 E/UploadActivity:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
 17721-17721 E/UploadActivity:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:932)
 17721-17721 E/UploadActivity:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:748)
 17721-17721 E/UploadActivity:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I am getting the above exception, I am using the code from

https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-android-samples/tree/master/S3TransferUtilitySample

Comment: Are you on Wifi or cellular or switching between those? This may happen if the network is flaky. BTW, what are the Android API version and the AWS Android SDK version?